# Can I route an ASP request from a client on my local LAN to an IIS server on a corporate LAN that I connect to with a VPN?

Tags: tcp, vpn

I work at home and use a VPN to connect my Windows dev machine to a corporate LAN. I have produced an Android app that connects to my local LAN over Wi-Fi and uses HTTP to call a web service hosted on the dev box. So far so good, but I would like to test the Android app calling an instance of the web service that is hosted on one of the corporate servers. I am hoping to write an app that will listen for HTTP requests arriving at my dev box (from the Android app) and re-route them over the VPN to the corporate server. As is probably obvious, I am largely ignorant wrt the vast subject that is networking, have been googling TCP/IP tutorials but can not seem to find the information that I need. So my questions are 1) is what I am hoping to do feasible?, and 2) what are the specific subject areas within networking that I should be studying to achieve my aims?